# .NET MAUI app only runs on emulator or device connected to USB debugger

Tags: android, .net, startup, maui, .net-maui

I'm a novice at mobile development with Xamarin Forms and .NET MAUI.
My App runs fine in debug mode but crashes on startup otherwise.

Can somebody tell me how to find the logging info I need to figure out what is going on? Or maybe someone else has had this same issue.

Kind of a shame that I have a bug that only strikes when there's no debugger running...

I've tried uninstalling the app and reinstalling it. Cleaning the solution. Rebuilding. Restarting the Windows Machine. No help.

Comment: any Console.Writeline statements will be captured in the log, which you can view with ADB or XCode

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is that it runs just fine when I run it in from Visual Studio, but if I close it, and reopen it (on the emulator or either of two physical devices) all I get is the purple .NET logo splash screen and then it just closes with no messages. Is there a way to view activity logs on the emulator while it's running independently?

Comment: Same for me, did you find a way to proceed or debug this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, what was causing it for me was having spaces in the Assembly Name.

Right click on the solution, click Properties, under General make sure Assembly Name doesn't have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm similar issues as Wandtke, creating a .Net/Maui/Blazer app with spaces or parentheses, the App will crash without the debugger connected. I followed Wandtke directions and changed the Assembly name from $(MSBuildProjectName), which would resolve to MauiApp2(Test8) in my test, to simply MauiApp2 and it ran fine without the debugger running.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that my backend api was http and not https.